# Azure IOT Hub MQTT Messages Lost on Internet drop

Tags: azure, debian, azure-iot-hub

We are using `azure-iot-device-mqtt` node package to connect a debian computer to the Azure IOT Hub. We have noticed that when the Internet drops (i.e. we disconnect it) `Device Explorer` thinks the device is still connected (for about 10 seconds) and messages being fired in this period do not reach the device (or get queued). After 10 seconds they appear in the Device Explorer queue. Also the device still thinks it's connected and does not recover the connection.

We have tried package versions 1.1.17 and 1.2.1 and have the same symptoms on both.

```
var clientFromConnectionString = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').clientFromConnectionString;
var Message = require('azure-iot-device').Message;

var connectionString = 'xxx';

var client = clientFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var connectCallback = function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Could not connect: ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log('Client connected');
    var message = new Message('some data from my device');
    client.sendEvent(message, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err.toString());
    });

    client.on('message', function (msg) { 
      console.log(msg); 
      client.complete(msg, function () {
        console.log('completed');
      });
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function () { 
      console.log("disconnect");
    });
  }
};
client.open(connectCallback);
```

N.b We require MQTT as we are using direct-method functionality.

With the AMQP package as soon as any disconnection the messages from the cloud instantly go into the queue.

Summary of issues:

- MQTT messages lost for first 10-15 seconds of disconnection (After this they are queued cloud side).
- MQTT+AMQP clients does not detect disconnects.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Interestingly, I just tested the above code in Windows and the messages still get lost (but the disconnect method fires).

Comment: following up here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/issues/132. Github is our preferred way of tracking bugs in the SDK

Comment: Issue has been fixed in GitHub (see link shared by pierreca above)